# day-by-day calendar in ReactJS logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that calls `goNextDay` and another that calls `goPreviousDay`. Both go to the correct month but doesn't set the day to `prevMonthDays` in last month if day === 1 or set day in next month to 1 if day === thisMonthDays.

Here is the same code as below, but with any forthcoming improvements.

> Go to src>UIConainers>Calendar>CalSlideDrawer.js

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14

the CalSlideDrawer.js is found by top-left logo icon (after pressing the inbox icon if you're starting on the purple screen)

```
export const getMonthDays = (month, year) => {
  const months30 = [4, 6, 9, 11];
  const leapYear = year % 4 === 0;
  return month === 2
    ? leapYear
      ? 29
      : 28
    : months30.includes(month)
    ? 30
    : 31;
};

export const goPreviousDay = (day, month, year) => {
  const prevMonthDays = getMonthDays(month, year);
  if (day <= 1) {
    const prevMonth = (month > 1) ? month - 1 : 12;
    const prevMonthYear = (month > 1) ? year : year - 1;
    return { month: prevMonth, year: prevMonthYear };
  }
  const prevDay = (day < 2) ? prevMonthDays : day - 1;
  return { day: prevDay, month, year };
};

export const goNextDay = (day, month, year) => {
  const thisMonthDays = getMonthDays(month, year);
  if (day === thisMonthDays) {
    const nextMonth = month < 12 ? month + 1 : 1;
    const nextMonthYear = month < 12 ? year : year + 1;
    return { month: nextMonth, year: nextMonthYear };
  }
  const nextDay = day === thisMonthDays ? 1: day + 1;
  return { day: nextDay, month, year };
};
```

Thanks for reading. Can you tell what is wrong with my logic? Please let me know, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doesn't return `day` from the method if day === 1. So, day doesn't change. Because you have `return` keyword in your if statement. So if day <= 1, this code block won't run because of `return` keyword.

```
    return { month: prevMonth, year: prevMonthYear }; // This breaks the block.
}
const prevDay = (day < 2) ? prevMonthDays : day - 1; // won't run if day === 1
return { day: prevDay, month, year };
```

So, you can fix it like that:

```
export const goPreviousDay = (day, month, year) => {
  const prevMonthDays = getMonthDays(month, year);
  let newDay, newMonth, newYear;

  if (day <= 1) {
    newDay = prevMonthDays;
    newMonth = (month > 1) ? month - 1 : 12;
    newYear = (month > 1) ? year : year - 1;
  } else {
    newDay = day - 1;
    newMonth = month;
    newYear = year;
  }

  return { day: newDay, month: newMonth, year: newYear };
};
```

same thing for goNextDay method.

Comment: here is goNextDay method: ````export const goNextDay = (day, month, year) => {
  const thisMonthDays = getMonthDays(month, year);
  let newDay, newMonth, newYear;


  if (day >= thisMonthDays ) {
    newDay = 1;
    newMonth = month < 12 ? month + 1 : 1;
    newYear = month < 12 ? year : year + 1;
  } else {newDay = day +1; newMonth = month; newYear = year}
  return { day: newDay, month: newMonth, year: newYear };
}; ````

Comment: @NickCarducci exactly.

Comment: here is goPreviousDay method w/getMonthDays of previous month:`export const goPreviousDay = (day, month, year) => {
  let newprevMonth = (month > 1) ? month - 1 : 12;
  let newprevYear = (month > 1) ? year : year - 1;
  const prevMonthDays = getMonthDays(newprevMonth, newprevYear);
  let newDay, newMonth, newYear
  

  if (day <= 1) {
    newDay = prevMonthDays;
    newMonth = (month > 1) ? month - 1 : 12;
    newYear = (month > 1) ? year : year - 1;
  } else {newDay = day -1; newMonth = month; newYear = year}
  return { day: newDay, month: newMonth, year: newYear };
};` thx again